# How to use count() to get items between specific dates

Tags: python, django

With this code I am able to get all `orders` items that is related to `Article` but here is the problem, I want to get the number of `orders` that are between two dates that are between the assigned `timestamp`.How can I do it?

```
class Order(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ordersauthor')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ordersarticle')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_price = models.FloatField(default='0', validators=[MaxValueValidator(99999999999999999999)])

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_orders(self, language):
        return language.ordersarticle.count()
```

Initial Output:

```
{
            .....,
             "orders": 4, // All orders
        },
```

Expected Output:

```
{
            .....,
             "orders": 1, // Orders between 4th and 11th of march (Example)
        },
```

Update:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    search_fields = ['^articlechoices__item','^caption','^name']
    filterset_fields = ['author','price','location','category']
```

Comment: So where are the timestamps that specify the range?

Comment: Can you also share the (view)set?

Comment: There is no timestamp that specify between range , it is required to be always set between 7 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from datetime import date


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_orders(self, language):
        return language.ordersarticle.filter(
            timestamp__range=(date(2024, 3, 4), date(2024, 3, 7))
        ).count()
```

but this is *not* a good idea: if you have to serialize for example *multiple* such `Article`s, it will make a query *per* item.

We can calculate these in advance with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q


class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    search_fields = ['^articlechoices__item', '^caption', '^name']
    filterset_fields = ['author', 'price', 'location', 'category']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .annotate(
                num_orders=Count(
                    'ordersarticle',
                    filter=Q(
                        ordersarticle__timestamp__range=(date(2024, 3, 4), date(2024, 3, 7))
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
```

and serialize with:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='num_orders')

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Order`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`ordersauthor`</s> relation to `orders`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it between starting `now` and ending at `7 days ago`?

Comment: use `date.today()` and `date.today() + timedelta(days=7)` instead of the `date(2024, 3, 4)`, etc.